# Get the original / raw template value of ng-content

Tags: angular, ng-content

Is it possible to get the pre-processed value of `ng-content`?
I am building design-system docs and want to display the example code without repeating myself

**html**:

```
<tr>
  <td #contentEl>
    <ng-content #projected></ng-content>
  </td>
  <td>
    <mat-icon (click)="copyTagToClipboard()">content_paste</mat-icon>
  </td>
  <td>
    <pre>{{ contentEl.innerHTML }}</pre>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**typescript**

```
export class CodeExampleComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('contentEl') contentEl: HTMLTableCellElement;
  @ContentChild('template') template;
  @ViewChild('projected', { read: TemplateRef, static: true }) content;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.content);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log(this.template);
  }
  
  copyTagToClipboard() {
    if (!this.contentEl) return;
    copyToClipboard(this.contentEl.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
  <app-code-example>
    <template #template><app-footnote>Footnote</app-footnote></template>
  </app-code-example>
```

All I can ever get is the angular rendered contents of the ng-content/template, not the original raw template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily answer your question about getting the pre-processed HTML from `ng-content`. However this approach can be used to solve your issue about displaying the HTML as an example. You can import the raw html as a string and use it as a variable. What I like to do is then create a component or multiple components that demonstrates usage of some component I'm documenting.

This is kind of a lot, so I put it all in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhyzub?file=src/app/app.component.html) to try and demonstrate.

Create a file right in the `src` directory called `typings.d.ts` that allows us to import html files as text.

```
declare module "*.html" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

Create an abstract class that all our example component need to implement. We need it to be abstract because we're going to be using `QueryList` later.

```
export abstract class Example {
  templateText: string; //the raw html to display 
}
```

Create a example wrapper component that displays the live example, the raw html and has your copy button

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, Input, QueryList } from "@angular/core";
import { Example } from "../example";

@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>{{label}}</h1>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    
        <br />
        <button (click)="copyTagToClipboard()">Copy Content</button>
    
        <div>
            <pre>{{ example.templateText }}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ExampleComponent{
  @Input() label: string; 
  
  @ContentChildren(Example) items: QueryList<Example>;
  example: Example;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    //grab the first thing that implements the "Example" interface
    //hypothetically this component could be re-worked to display multiple examples!
    this.example = this.items.toArray()[0];    
  }

  copyTagToClipboard() {
    alert(this.example.templateText);
  }
}
```

Build a component that demonstrates how to use whatever component you are documenting. Note how we import the html file as a variable and use it as an attribute of the component, satisfying the interface. Don't forget to set up the providers so `QueryList` can pick up on the component. You can then build as many of these examples as you need, perhaps a different component per use case.

```
import { Component, TemplateRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Example } from "../example";

// See typings.d.ts, which sets up the module that allows us to do this
import * as template from "./my-component-example.component.html";
// or const template = `<app-my-component [label]="myLabelValue"></app-my-component>`;

@Component({
  selector: "app-my-component-example",
  template,
  styleUrls: ["./my-component-example.component.css"],

  //this is so the QueryList works in the example wrapper
  providers: [{ provide: Example, useExisting: MyComponentExampleComponent }]
})
export class MyComponentExampleComponent implements Example {
  myLabelValue = "Test Label!!";
  templateText = template.default;
}
```

Lastly, put it all together

```
<app-example label="Basic Example">
  <app-my-component-example></app-my-component-example>
</app-example>
```

I feel like with this approach there's a lot of flexibility in you how create each example.

Comment: That's ingenious. Worth noting for brevity we could put `my-component-example.component.html` into a constant string.